# How to change default pull strategy in EGit

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

How can I change the git pull strategy (rebase / merge / none) in eclipse?

It seems I can only set it when I check out a new branch but can't change it afterwards.

This seems really odd or is it not allowed to change the pull strategy on an existing branch?

Answer (score 8):

1. Open the Git Repositories view
2. Expand the repository in question
3. Expand Branches → Local
4. Right click on the branch and select *Configure Branch*
5. Toggle the *Rebase* flag or change the *Upstream Branch*

If *Configure Branch* is not available, update EGit to at least 2.0, or use the [nightly update site](http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates-nightly).